# Numpy subtraction from two arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays like below

```
a=np.array([11,12])
b=np.array([9])

#a-b should be [2,12]
```

I want to subtract both a & b such that result should [2,12]. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: Without defining `b` as the same size as `a`?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can zero-pad one of the array.

```
import numpy as np

n = max(len(a), len(b))
a_pad = np.pad(a, (0, n - len(a)), 'constant')
b_pad = np.pad(b, (0, n - len(b)), 'constant')

ans = a_pad - b_pad
```

Here `np.pad`'s second argument is `(#of left pads, #of right pads)`

Answer (score 2):

A similar method to @BlownhitherMa, would be to create an array of zeros the size of `a` (we can call it `c`), then put in `b`'s values where appropriate:

```
c = np.zeros_like(a)
c[np.indices(b.shape)] = b

>>> c
array([9, 0])

>>> a-c
array([ 2, 12])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest

a = np.array([11, 12])
b = np.array([9])

result = np.array([ai - bi for ai, bi in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=0)])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[ 2 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very long laid out solution.

```
diff =[]

n = min(len(a), len(b))
for i in range (n):
    diff.append(a[i] - b[i])
if len(a) > n:
    for i in range(n,len(a)):
        diff.append(a[i])
elif len(b) > n:
    for i in range(n,len(b)):
        diff.append(b[i])
diff=np.array(diff)
print(diff)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid unnecessary padding / temporaries by copying `a` and then subtracting `b` in-place:

```
# let numpy determine appropriate dtype
dtp = (a[:0]-b[:0]).dtype
# copy a
d = a.astype(dtp)
# subtract b
d[:b.size] -= b
```